# Unit testing grails controllers that use declarative exception handling

Tags: unit-testing, grails

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class SomeController {     
   def fooService

   def controllerMethod() {
       def bar = fooService.doSomething()
       // render bar to user - success case
   }

   def fooExceptionHandler(FooException e) {
       // log, render error page, etc... 
   }
}
```

Based on [grails' new declarative controller exception handling mechanism](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllerExceptionHandling), if `fooService.doSomething()` throws an exception, grails will call fooExceptionHandler for me. Great.

Now when I unit test this method (test class uses the `@TestFor(SomeController)` annotation), this will fail saying that we expected a FooException but got nothing.

```
@Test(expected=FooException)
def doSomethingThrowsFooException() {
   // override default service behavior, trigger a FooException 
   controller.fooService = [ doSomething: { throw new FooException() }] 
   controller.controllerMethod()
}
```

However, this works:

```
@Test
def doSomethingThrowsFooException() {
   // override default service behavior, trigger a FooException 
   controller.fooService = [ doSomething: { throw new FooException() }] 
   controller.controllerMethod()
   assert response.json == false
}
```

So the only way to test this method is by asserting that the response was what was expected but due to the declarative exception handling, this logic is now somewhere else (tested in isolation), not in the unit of code I am testing. Shouldn't my unit test only verify that the exception was propagated out of the controller method?

Answer (score 1):

I would test the fooService integration with your controller in an integration test if possible, but I think that's only really testable sensibly in a functional test. You're really testing Grails - you're verifying that documented behavior occurs in your app.

If you add some code to throw an exception and then extra code to catch it and route it to the handler, you're just mocking out the stuff that Grails provides. Tests of that just test your mocking code, but have little to do with how well your code will work in production.

The unit test opportunity here is inside `fooExceptionHandler`. Test that given an exception, you do the right thing with it.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Before the declarative exception handling, my controller put a try/catch around the service call and in the catch I rendered the error page. Now that try/catch is not needed, are you saying that I do not need to unit test this path at all? (I do understand what you are saying about unit testing fooExceptionHandler)